# How to wrap ruby variable in parenthesis if it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a function returning a string of interpolated ruby values.

```
def test_field_name
  "#{self.test_field.test.name} #{self.result.position if self.result.sequence.results.count > 1} - #{self.test_field.name}"
end
```

I can't figure out how to wrap the `self.result.position` in parentheses if it exists, but leave the parentheses out when it doesn't.

I'd like the two possible outputs to be:

```
TestName - TestFieldName
```

or

```
TestName (2) - TestFieldName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to do this in a single line?
You could do something like the following:

```
def test_field_name
  arr = [self.test_field.test.name]
  arr << "(#{self.result.position})" if self.result.sequence.results.count > 1
  arr << "- #{self.test_field.name}"
  arr.join(' ')
end
```

But if you really want to do it in a single line, a solution could be:

```
def test_field_name
  "#{self.test_field.test.name}#{(' (' + self.result.position + ')') if self.result.sequence.results.count > 1} - #{self.test_field.name}"
end
```

Comment: No, I don't actually.  Thank you so much.  Works beautifully.  I'm not sure why I stayed so focused on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Add another method to encapsulate the logic with an `if...else` branch.

```
def test_field_name
  "#{self.test_field.test.name} #{self.result_position}- #{self.test_field.name}"
end

def result_position
  self.result.sequence.results.count > 1 ? "(#{self.result.position}) " : ""
end
```